Active Directory userParameter
Need native value support.
Recently, I referred to the Microsoft blog to study userparameter value
link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tsts/0bd1a91d-3cd6-4e97-b5fa-5cf35d90f005
I have some doubts,

What was the default value first 96 reserved bytes?
Second thing is, any one of the TS property was set in ADuser property by UI. other TS property also set by default value (why do I think about this? because I set "Disconnect session Time" the byte length of the userParameter is above 700 )

